# Call callback function on esc in Angular UI Bootstrap's modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using a modal of Angular UI Bootstrap that can be closed via a Cancel button or via ESC. As I have to do some cleaning when it closes, I've written the 'cancel' method in the scope, but this is only called when clicking this Cancel button, how could I do to call this cleaning functions when it closes on ESC too?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When a modal is dismissed (either by pressing ESC or clicking on backdrop) a promise returned from the `$modal.open` method call is *rejected*. So you can react on ESC press by adding error handler to the returned promise. This is illustrated in the example available from the demo page: http://plnkr.co/edit/xMTr78WJQbKyHsA53gyv?p=preview
(see this line: `$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());`)

Comment: can the information in the modal scope be accessed when dismissed is called?

Answer (score 8):

thanks @pkozlowski.opensource

i directly knew what to do :)

```
var modalWindow = $modal.open({
    windowClass: 'modal myKewlDialog',
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/myKewlModalTemplate.html',
    controller: 'myKewlModalController'
});

modalWindow.result.then(function (result) {
    updateUI();
}, function (result) {
    updateUI();
});
```

Comment: if U trigger the same function for closing and dismiss the modal I would suggest to use ['finally'](function(){....}) instead of duplicate triggers ;)

Comment: good point! i don't know anymore if i was really calling the updateUI-fn in both cases...